# How do I select all check box when I click on Select button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML page which have multiple check boxes and individually they can be checked. I have button `select`, so what I am suppose to do  is. When I click on select all the check boxes should get selected, and deselected.

**Html**

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectAll').click(function(event) {  //on click 
        if(this.checked) { // check select status
            $('.btn-chk').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
            });
        }else{
            $('.btn-chk').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
            });         

        }
    });
    
});
</script>


<table id="example" cellspacing="0" width="20%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
   <th><button type="button" id="selectAll" class="myClass">Select</button></th>
  <th>number</th>
        <th>company</th>
  <th> Type</th>
  <th> Address</th>
  <th>Code</th>
 </tr>               
 </thead>
   

<tbody>          
  <tr>           
    <td><span class="button-checkbox">
      <button type="button" class="btn-chk" data-color="success"></button>
      <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" />
       </span>
  </td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>APPLE</td>
  <td>IT</td>
  <td>San Jones</td>
     <td>US</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td><span class="button-checkbox">
  <button type="button" class="btn-chk" data-color="success"></button>
     <input type="checkbox" class="hidden"  />
  </span>
        </td>
          <td>2</td>
    <td>DELL</td>
    <td>IT</td>
          <td>San Jones</td>
          <td>US</td>
      </tr>
  
      <tr>
        <td><span class="button-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn-chk" data-color="success"></button>                                                           
    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden"  />
       </span>
    </td>
 <td>3</td>
 <td>Amazon</td>
 <td>IT</td>
 <td>San Jones</td>
 <td>US</td>
 </tr>
  
 <tr>
 <td><span class="button-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn-chk" data-color="success"></button>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden"  />
    </span>
 </td>
 <td>4</td>
 <td>Microsoft</td>
 <td>IT</td>
 <td>San Jones</td>
 <td>US</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
         
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image]

In the image I have select button. what I want is when I click on select button all the check boxes should get selected

Comment: I don't understand, you're checking if the select button is checked and using the result to decide whether you select all or not... that won't work. A button can't be checked?

Comment: Are you after this kind of functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/Puddster/k9ryt981/?  When you click the top button, all underneath are checked?

Comment: You are not looping through each checkbox. Change .btn-chk to .hidden to loop through all the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#selectAll` is a button, it doesn't have a `checked` property, but one could emulate that with a data attribute instead.

Secondly, `.btn-chk` isn't a checkbox either, so it can't be checked, you have to target the checkboxes

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectAll').click(function(event) {
        var checked = !$(this).data('checked');

        $('.btn-chk').next().prop('checked', checked);

        $(this).data('checked', checked);
    });

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/sLbbtqtL/2/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to toggle the checkbox state, you can do like this

```
var chkd = true;
$('#selectAll').click(function(event) {
    $(":checkbox").prop("checked", chkd);
    chkd = !chkd;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kux7x16y/8/)

Answer (score 1):

An simple way is like below:

```
$(function() {
    $('#selectAll').click(function() {
        $(':checkbox').prop('checked', !$(':checkbox').prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

**[The Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/sLbbtqtL/1/)**

Comment: check the first checkbox , and then click the select button.Then repeat the same step with the second checkbox and see the difference

Answer (score 1):

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manideep/3w9tLkdb/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#selectAll').click(function() {
        $(':checkbox').prop('checked', !$(':checkbox').prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

You can simply use it
For more info on jQuery visit [w3schools-jquery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
var checked = true;
$('#selectAll').click(function(event) {
    $('table tr').each(function( index ) {
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop(checked, true);
    });
    checked = !checked;
});
```

Comment: I think OP wants to also deselect checkboxes when the button is clicked again.

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery code to

```
 $('#selectAll').click(function(event) {  //on click 
    if($('.hidden').prop('checked') == false) { // check select status
        $('.hidden').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
            this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
        });
    }else{
        $('.hidden').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
            this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
        });         

    }
});
```

This will toggle between `checked` and `unchecked` of the `checkboxes` when you click the `button`.

Answer (score 0):

inside the "click" function "this" is button and not a checkbox. and button property checked is underfined.
"$('.btn-chk').each" - is loop on each element with class ".btn-chk", in your HTML is buttons and not an checkboxes.

in your context the "#selectAll" must be a checkbox and put class '.btn-chk' on your checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this also with `':checkbox'` selector.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#selectAll').on('click', function () {
        $(':checkbox').each(function () {

            $(this).click();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely works.

```
$("#selectAll").click(function(){
    var checked = !$(this).data('checked');
    $('.btn-chk').prop('checked', checked);         
    $(this).data('checked', checked);
});
```