# Select all check boxes using button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML page which have multiple check boxes and individually they can be checked. I have button select, so what I am suppose to do is. When I click on select all the check boxes should get selected, thousands record.

**This is my page**

```html
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>monitoring</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
         </head>                   
        <table id="example" class="myclass"/>
        <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>
          <button type="button" id="selectAll" class="main">
          <span class="sub"></span> Select </button></th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Company</th>
         <th>Employee Type</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                    
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>varun</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Rahuk</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>johm Doe</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Sam</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Lara</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Jay</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Tom</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>
                                
        </tbody>
        </table>
            
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: _when user click on select it should select all thousands record_ for this there are ways, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').on('click', '#selectAll', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('allChecked')) {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]', '#example').prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]', '#example').prop('checked', true);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('allChecked');
  })
});
```

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tb8cm760/21/)

This will add a class, *allChecked*, on the "Select All" button when all items have been checked (and remove it when all are unchecked). Also, it will only look within the `#example` (your table with id *example*) context. This can be tweaked to your liking of course, as with anything.

Edit:

And to make sure that your jQuery is loaded. Try this script tag instead (replace your current):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Edit:
Just updated the syntax in fiddle for `<table>` tag as it was not the self closing tag

Comment: your example is working here 'Example on jsFiddle' but when I am using script into my file its not working. I have also included the allChecked class in SelectAll butoon

Comment: You shouldn't need to add any classes. You probably just need to make sure that everything is loaded correctly: See my update in answer above.

Comment: @varun Also, what version of jQuery is hiding behind `jquery.js`? I would make sure that jQuery is really loaded.

Comment: @varun Try the script tag I posted in my answer.

Comment: please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('#selectAll').click(function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    $(this).closest('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).hasClass('clicked'))
});
```

---

In this code what happening is:

1. First you bind the click on the button.
2. After click toggle a dummy classname to the button.
3. Then traverse up the the table and find all the checkboxes.
4. then change the property `checked` to `true/false` which depends on the class added to the button.

Comment: is it a good idea to solve the problem, when OP doesn't show a sign of trying to do it by himself?

Comment: @Regent yeah that's right. I guess OP has to provide some of their tries.

Comment: @Regent . A similar question was asked by the OP yesterday here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823843/how-do-i-select-all-check-box-when-i-click-on-select-button-using-jquerry . Is it allowed? I am not sure , thats y asking.

Comment: @Sourabh- yesterday i asked the same question and I accepted  the answer as well. I am totally new in jquery.  yesterday answer was working in my demo file but when I am using the same script in my original file its not working. I tried a lot,but it did not work. I am really dam confuse why its not working.Its not my motive to post question and accept answer and earn bounty.

Comment: @Sourabh- instead of posting current code saying that it doesn't work and describing what this code is supposed to do, OP just asks question again. The real problem is that it looks like OP doesn't bother to learn how to debug things by himself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8wwzaw89/)

```
$("#selectAll").on("click", function () {
    $("#example tr").each( function() {
             $(this).find("input").attr('checked', true);             
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

very good explanation here.
here it with answer **http://www.sanwebe.com/2014/01/how-to-select-all-deselect-checkboxes-jquery**

Comment: While link might provide explanation, you should post the solution here.

Comment: on link everything is described perfectly, so its better to clear the concept from the link. not only getting the solutions. @Regent

Comment: @XeeShan. [Link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) only answers are discouraged in SO as the link may become obsolete after some days. And also _since it requires you to go off-site to find a solution. We want solutions to be on the site_ . Quoted it from [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251007/3894168)