# How can I select all checkboxes from all the pages in a jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have HTML page which have multiple checkboxes and individually they can be checked. I have button for "*Select All*" and when I click on this button all the checkboxes should get selected, and when I click again on the same button all the checkboxes should get deselected **from all pages**.

In my original program there are thousands of records, but at a time 10 records are getting display, but when user click on select it should select all thousands record.

I am using [jQuery Datatables plug-in](https://datatables.net/) for displaying the data. It provides pagination, searching, sorting etc. so at a time I am displaying only 10 records on my current page. if I click on next or page number which is provided by Bootstrap Datatable another 10 records will be displayed. As mention in the problem I want to select all check-boxes from all the pages.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('body').on('click', '#selectAll', function () {
      if ($(this).hasClass('allChecked')) {
         $('input[type="checkbox"]', '#example').prop('checked', false);
      } else {
       $('input[type="checkbox"]', '#example').prop('checked', true);
       }
       $(this).toggleClass('allChecked');
     })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>monitoring</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
         </head>
        <body>
        <table id="example" class="myclass">
        <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>
          <button type="button" id="selectAll" class="main">
          <span class="sub"></span> Select </button></th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Company</th>
         <th>Employee Type</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                    
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>varun</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Rahuk</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>johm Doe</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Sam</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Lara</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Jay</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Tom</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>
                                
        </tbody>
        </table>
            
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select all check boxes using button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841547/select-all-check-boxes-using-button)

Comment: The `table`tag is not a self-closing tag, please change `<table id="example" class="myclass"/>` and remove the `/`

Comment: You posted same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841547/select-all-check-boxes-using-button and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823843/how-do-i-select-all-check-box-when-i-click-on-select-button-using-jquerry? **Use edit links on the same questions**

Comment: Your code should work. Can you share the error you are getting or the issue that you are facing? Why are you posting same question again, plz edit your previous question or tell us the actual issue you are facing.

Comment: @Sourabh it is working on a current page but what I want is when I clicked on a button it should select all the check boxes fro all the pages

Comment: @varun. What do you mean by _all pages_, isn't your complete table in 1 page? How are you displaying your table in different pages? Please add this info in your question so that ppl here can help you better.

Comment: @Mackan - we need to initialize our table using dataTable. so we do it like that. $(document).ready(function(){ $('#example').DataTable(); }); and we need to import some bootstrap.js provided by Bootstrap dataTable itself. you can follow this link to get more info https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        stateSave: true
    });

    var allPages = oTable.fnGetNodes();

    $('body').on('click', '#selectAll', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('allChecked')) {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]', allPages).prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]', allPages).prop('checked', true);
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('allChecked');
    })
});
```

The magic should happen in `fnGetNodes()`:

> **fnGetNodes()**: Get an array of the TR nodes that are used in the table's body

**Edit**

This alternative solution is mostly for debugging (to see if it works). Hardly optimal code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        stateSave: true
    });

    var allPages = oTable.cells( ).nodes( );

    $('#selectAll').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('allChecked')) {
            $(allPages).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $(allPages).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('allChecked');
    })
});
```

Comment: sorry for being so dumb but can you help me with this. I am totally new with this. or just give an idea how do I do that

Comment: @varun I've updated both codes a bit - since the newer version of _DataTables_ apparently use another definition of options.

Comment: you are genius. finally you did it. the first code finally worked

Comment: Be aware this won't work if you're using [DataTable.select](https://datatables.net/reference/option/select) and outputting the `x rows selected`. The checkboxes will need to be actually triggered before Datatables registers it.

Comment: This is fine till we are not searching anything. If we use any filter or search, then the select all option got disappeared. Is it possible to have the select all option available after filtering also?

Comment: @Mackan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341158/how-to-pass-checked-data-from-jquery-data-table-pagination-to-struts-action-clas

Answer (score 5):

Use datatable $ instance for selections https://datatables.net/docs/DataTables/1.9.4/#$

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        stateSave: true
    });

    $("#selectAll").on("change", function(){
        oTable.$("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $(this.checked));  
    });
});
```

Comment: This option is a very clean option to use and I used it myself, however it needs to be updated to $(this).is(":checked")

Answer (score 3):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/vj2hnxh7/)**

Easiest way is to use following jQuery code:

**//EDIT** on the second click, you now remove all checked boxes.

```js
$('#selectAll').click(function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('checkedAll')) {
      $('input').prop('checked', false);   
      $(this).removeClass('checkedAll');
    } else {
      $('input').prop('checked', true);
      $(this).addClass('checkedAll');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>monitoring</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
         </head>                   <body>
        <table id="example" class="myclass"/>
        <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>
          <button type="button" id="selectAll" class="main">
          <span class="sub"></span> Select </button></th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Company</th>
         <th>Employee Type</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                    
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>varun</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Rahuk</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>johm Doe</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Sam</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Lara</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Jay</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Tom</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>
                                
        </tbody>
        </table>
            
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: it is working? you can run the code snippet above. don't forget to add the jquery library in your own snippet!

Comment: I have included the jQuery library in my code but still its not working

Comment: i even tried it with your code, which is working as well. maybe you can provide us with a failure message?

Comment: I'd say this is actually a step worse than the original code (well, I wrote the function he uses so I'm biased) ;) This does not address the users request though: How to select/unselect from _all pages_

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```js
   if ($(this).hasClass('allChecked')) {
     $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', 'checked')
   } else {
     $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', 'false')
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

use **dataTables.checkboxes.min.js** and use `"selectAllPages" : false` . It should be work for selection of each page records .

Answer (score 0):

```
var oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, 'All']]
    // stateSave: true
});
$('#selectAll').on('change', function() {
    oTable.$('.student_id:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});

jQuery(document).on('change', '.student_id', function() {
    if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
        if (jQuery('.student_id:checked').length == jQuery('.student_id').length) {
            jQuery('#selectAll').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            jQuery('#selectAll').prop('checked', false);
        }
    } else {
        jQuery('#selectAll').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please consider providing a short explanation of your answer for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('body').on('click', '#selectAll', function () {
      if ($(this).hasClass('allChecked')) {
         $('input[type="checkbox"]', '#example').prop('checked', false);
      } else {
       $('input[type="checkbox"]', '#example').prop('checked', true);
       }
       $(this).toggleClass('allChecked');
     })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>monitoring</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
         </head>
        <body>
        <table id="example" class="myclass">
        <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>
          <button type="button" id="selectAll" class="main">
          <span class="sub"></span> Select </button></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Employee Type</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                                                  
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>varun</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Rahuk</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>johm Doe</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Sam</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Lara</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Jay</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/>
        </td>
        <td>Tom</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>US</td>
        </tr>
                                                                                                        
        </tbody>
        </table>
                        
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).