# jQuery datatable with pagination select all checkboxes not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

I have ASP.NET GridView with jquery datatable plugin applied with pagination enabled. select all and de-selectall button working fine i.e. it is changing the css of all rows to active but the checkbox state is only changing on current page and not on all pages of datatable.
I want to select all checkboxes of all the pages of datatable on clicking selectall button.

Comment: I answered the exact same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896599/how-can-i-select-all-checkboxes-from-all-the-pages-in-a-jquery-datatable/29898352#29898352

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this one.
Assuming that  Check all is your Submit button:

```
 <input type="submit" name="checkall" title="Check All Rows"/> 

 $('#checkall').click( function() {
 $('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).attr('checked','checked');
 return false; // to avoid refreshing the page
 } );
```

It will select all the checkboxes (even hidden) in the datatable

Answer (score 0):

on button click
var dt = $("#datatable").dataTable() <-- "#datatable" = Your table Id

$('input', dt.fnGetNodes()).attr('checked','checked');