# How to pass checked data from jQuery data table pagination to struts action class

Tags: jquery, pagination, struts2, datatables

I'm trying to send data from jQuery data table pagination to the struts action class and the problem I'm facing is I'm able to send only the current page data which displayed on browser while submit the form.
Like I have three page in jQuery data table pagination in each page I select like one record from page1, three record from  page2 and two record from   page3

while am submit the current page is page2 so I will get only three but it should come six

```
<s:form action="toactionClass" method="post">
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                   <th><a href="#" id="selectall">Select all</a></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                     <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                  <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2012/03/29</td>
                    <td>$433,060</td>
                     <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Airi Satou</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                    <td>2008/11/28</td>
                    <td>$162,700</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2012/12/02</td>
                    <td>$372,000</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>2012/08/06</td>
                    <td>$137,500</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>55</td>
                    <td>2010/10/14</td>
                    <td>$327,900</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>39</td>
                    <td>2009/09/15</td>
                    <td>$205,500</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>2008/12/13</td>
                    <td>$103,600</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>2008/12/19</td>
                    <td>$90,560</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                    <td>Support Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2013/03/03</td>
                    <td>$342,000</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>36</td>
                    <td>2008/10/16</td>
                    <td>$470,600</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                    <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>43</td>
                    <td>2012/12/18</td>
                    <td>$313,500</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>19</td>
                    <td>2010/03/17</td>
                    <td>$385,750</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michael Silva</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2012/11/27</td>
                    <td>$198,500</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                    <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>2010/06/09</td>
                    <td>$725,000</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gloria Little</td>
                    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>2009/04/10</td>
                    <td>$237,500</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>41</td>
                    <td>2012/10/13</td>
                    <td>$132,000</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dai Rios</td>
                    <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>35</td>
                    <td>2012/09/26</td>
                    <td>$217,500</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                    <td>Development Lead</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>2011/09/03</td>
                    <td>$345,000</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                    <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>40</td>
                    <td>2009/06/25</td>
                    <td>$675,000</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                    <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td>2011/12/12</td>
                    <td>$106,450</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>Sidney</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>2010/09/20</td>
                    <td>$85,600</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                    <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2009/10/09</td>
                    <td>$1,200,000</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>42</td>
                    <td>2010/12/22</td>
                    <td>$92,575</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>28</td>
                    <td>2010/11/14</td>
                    <td>$357,650</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>28</td>
                    <td>2011/06/07</td>
                    <td>$206,850</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fiona Green</td>
                    <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>48</td>
                    <td>2010/03/11</td>
                    <td>$850,000</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shou Itou</td>
                    <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                    <td>2011/08/14</td>
                    <td>$163,000</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michelle House</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>Sidney</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>2011/06/02</td>
                    <td>$95,400</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Suki Burks</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                    <td>2009/10/22</td>
                    <td>$114,500</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                    <td>Technical Author</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/05/07</td>
                    <td>$145,000</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                    <td>Team Leader</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2008/10/26</td>
                    <td>$235,500</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                    <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>2011/03/09</td>
                    <td>$324,050</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Unity Butler</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2009/12/09</td>
                    <td>$85,675</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>51</td>
                    <td>2008/12/16</td>
                    <td>$164,500</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                    <td>Secretary</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>41</td>
                    <td>2010/02/12</td>
                    <td>$109,850</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                    <td>Financial Controller</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>62</td>
                    <td>2009/02/14</td>
                    <td>$452,500</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>2008/12/11</td>
                    <td>$136,200</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                    <td>Director</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>65</td>
                    <td>2008/09/26</td>
                    <td>$645,750</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>2011/02/03</td>
                    <td>$234,500</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>38</td>
                    <td>2011/05/03</td>
                    <td>$163,500</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>2009/08/19</td>
                    <td>$139,575</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Thor Walton</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2013/08/11</td>
                    <td>$98,540</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2009/07/07</td>
                    <td>$87,500</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                    <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>2012/04/09</td>
                    <td>$138,575</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2010/01/04</td>
                    <td>$125,250</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>56</td>
                    <td>2012/06/01</td>
                    <td>$115,000</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                    <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>43</td>
                    <td>2013/02/01</td>
                    <td>$75,650</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>2011/12/06</td>
                    <td>$145,600</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2011/03/21</td>
                    <td>$356,250</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Lael Greer</td>
                    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td>2009/02/27</td>
                    <td>$103,500</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>2010/07/14</td>
                    <td>$86,500</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shad Decker</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>51</td>
                    <td>2008/11/13</td>
                    <td>$183,000</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>29</td>
                    <td>2011/06/27</td>
                    <td>$183,000</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
<s:submit value="send"/>
</s:form>
```

Count of Selected Records

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var table =  $('#example').DataTable();

$("#selectall").click(function() {
    var rows = table.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();

    debugger;
    if($('input:checked', rows).length == rows.length){
       $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', false);
    }
    else{
       $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', true);
    }


    $('#dvcount').html($(rows).find("input:checked").length);


    });

    $("body").on("change","input",function() {

    var rows = table.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
    $('#dvcount').html($(rows).find("input:checked").length);

    });

  } );
```

Comment: @Roman C can you answered link

Comment: i only send that question i have not any reply thats why i put new post @Roman c

Comment: if you can answer mark it as duplicate answer or give a suggestion