# Select all checkbox from all pages of DataTable loaded from ajax & 10 records per ajax call

Tags: jquery, datatable

I've load my datatable using ajax.
for reach page I've trigger ajax call to get new records.

**Steps to create my DataTable & Delete Checked Records:**

1. Build 1st 10 records for 1st page by calling ajax call & click on page 2 call next 10 records.
2. When I checked some checkbox on Page 1 & Click on Page 2 checked some checkbox & click on delete button I've not get the Page checkbox checked Ids.

How Can I get Both page (Page 1 & Page 2) checkbox checked ids for records deletion?

**DataTable Code:**

```
var url="<?php echo base_url()?>users/get_users";
$('#datatable-checkbox').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "ajax":{  
            url:url,  
            type:"POST"  
        },
    "columnDefs":[  
        {  
            "targets":[0,5,6],  
            "orderable":false, 
        },                
    ]            
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896599/how-can-i-select-all-checkboxes-from-all-the-pages-in-a-jquery-datatable

Comment: you have two different tabs open for two pages or you have one tab and two pages on it .. right ?

Comment: I've load 10 records at time for one page using ajax & next 10 records by calling another ajax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select all checkboxes from all the pages in a jQuery DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896599/how-can-i-select-all-checkboxes-from-all-the-pages-in-a-jquery-datatable)

Comment: @markpsmith : In this question it's loading all records at time. I'm loading 10 records at time using ajax.

Comment: Read the question: _so at a time I am displaying only 10 records on my current page_

Comment: I've read the question but solution only works when datatable load all the records at time.