# DataTable paginate custom select all row

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I use [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) to display my table, I have 3 columns (cf. image)

The problem is that when I click on `All` is select just the displayed row of the pagination but when I change to page 2 or other, rows are not selected...

**DATATABLE DECLARE**

```
var table = $('#translations').DataTable({
    dom: 'rtl<"text-center" ip>',
    ordering: false,
    pageLength: 25
});
```

**TABLE THEAD**

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-1"><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" onClick="selectAll(this)">&nbsp;All</th>
        <th class="col-xs-5">Term</th>
        <th class="col-xs-6">Translation</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

**SELECT ALL ONCLICK**

```
function selectAll(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('selectCb');

    for(var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;

    }
}
```

[image: Screen table]

Comment: Should "All" select just the displayed rows? Right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select all checkboxes from all the pages in a jQuery DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896599/how-can-i-select-all-checkboxes-from-all-the-pages-in-a-jquery-datatable)

Comment: hey @Yuri, no `All` should select the rows of all the table, not just the one shown in the current pagination

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using jQuery on the DOM you only reach visible rows. You will need to access dataTables internal version of the table, i.e its "cache". Here is a "checkall" function iterating over all the rows, changing the checked state for a checkbox with the class .checkbox1 :

```
$('#select_all').click(function(event) {  //on click 
  var checked = this.checked;
  table.column(0).nodes().to$().each(function(index) {    
    if (checked) {
      $(this).find('.checkbox1').prop('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
      $(this).find('.checkbox1').removeProp('checked');            
    }
  });    
  table.draw();
});
```

You can remove that Onclick function if you use this code

Using [to$()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) let us work with jQuery on the content right away.

Comment: This woks to check all rows but when I try to retrieved all values with :
`$('#table tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
    // this = tr

    console.log(this.id);
});`

It just retrieved the current page checked rows

Comment: @AntoineD,  how could it be any different? You are using jQuery which only target visible rows (i.e DOM); If you want to iterate over all rows you must go through the API as well.

Comment: Yes I just figured this out, Thaks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This code runs when you click on page number.

```
$('#translation').on('page.dt', function () {
    var info = table.page.info();
    // put any code you want
});
```

You can implement all checklist inside the function. To obtain the current page number, use `info.page`. To obtain the total pages, use `info.pages`.

Answer (score 0):

Default datatable script will not uncheck the checkbox in pagination 
please change your checkbox name this  name="select_all[]"